# Why is integral of differential delta function equal to delta function?

Tags: dirac-delta

Why is integral of differential delta function equal to delta function?

I.e. as I've read elsewhere:

$$\int_A 1 d \delta_A=\int_A d \delta_A=\delta_A=\delta_x(A)$$

https://planetmath.org/diracmeasure

Intuitively one could compare it to $\int 1 dx=x$, but since $\delta_A$ is a piece-wise function ...

Also I understand the intuition as to why the integral "ought to" equal that. But not the reasoning of "integral of differential equals variable of differential".

Comment: Where do you find the notation $\delta_A$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that here $\delta_x$ is a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)), i.e. a function taking a set (belonging to some [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra)) and giving a nonnegative value. In this case, for any $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\delta_x(A) := \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x\in A \\
0 & \text{if } x\not\in A
\end{cases}
$$

I won't go into the [definitions of integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Lebesgue_integral) of functions w.r.t. a measure, but for the measure $\delta_x$ we have
$$
\int f \, d\delta_x = f(x).
$$
Here, the $d$ in front of $\delta_x$ doesn't mean differential, but is rather just a common notation for telling with respect to what measure the integral is done. Some mathematicians would instead write $\int f(t) \, \delta_x(dt).$

An integral restricted to a set $A$ is defined by 
$
\int_A f \, d\mu = \int \chi_A f \, d\mu,
$
where $f$ is a function, $\mu$ a measure, and $\chi_A$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $A$, defined by
$$
\chi_A(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x\in A \\
0 & \text{if } x\not\in A
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore,
$$
\int_A d\delta_x
= \int \chi_A \, d\delta_x
= \chi_A(x)
= \delta_x(A)
.
$$